# Get part of an integer in Python

Tags: python, integer

Is there an elegant way (maybe in `numpy`) to get a given part of a Python integer, eg say I want to get `90` from `1990`.

I can do:

```
my_integer = 1990
int(str(my_integer)[2:4])
# 90
```

But it is quite ugly.

Any other option?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to get part of an integer, as explained in my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`1990 % 100` would do the trick.

(`%` is the modulo operator and returns the remainder of the division, here 1990 = 19*100 + 90.)

---

*Added after answer was accepted:*

If you need something generic, try this:

```
def GetIntegerSlice(i, n, m):
  # return nth to mth digit of i (as int)
  l = math.floor(math.log10(i)) + 1
  return i / int(pow(10, l - m)) % int(pow(10, m - n + 1))
```

It will return the nth to mth digit of i (as int), i.e.

```
>>> GetIntegerSlice(123456, 3, 4)
34
```

Not sure it's an improvement over your suggestion, but it does not rely on string operations and was fun to write.

(Note: casting to `int` before doing the division (rather than only casting the result to `int` in the end) makes it work also for long integers.)

Comment: That's why I asked him.

Comment: UpperCamelCase is a **terrible** naming convention for a Python function, don't show this stuff to beginners and stop writing it. See [this PEP8 reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names) to see what the "standard" is. Even if you don't want to write lowercase with underscores, don't do upper camel case. It is a disgrace (in Python).

Answer (score 4):

Here is generic function for getting any number of last digits:

```
In [160]: def get_last_digits(num, digits=2):
   .....:         return num%10**digits
   .....:

In [161]: get_last_digits(1999)
Out[161]: 99

In [162]: get_last_digits(1999,3)
Out[162]: 999

In [166]: get_last_digits(1999,10)
Out[166]: 1999
```

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the use but if you for example know you only want the last two you can use the modulus operator like so: `1990%100` to get `90`.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe like this:

```
my_integer = 1990
my_integer % 100
```